# Compare Strings to get Unique values in Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja

I have a variable with list of node IP's and its respective Availability Zone.

```
seed = {
  10.18.13.12 = us-east-1a
  10.18.37.93 = us-east-1b
  10.18.68.147 = us-east-1a
  10.18.21.55 = us-east-1b
}
```

I will be using this variable in Jinja template but want to filter out the variable based on unique Avalability Zones and get the IP. I want to compare the Avalability Zones to get unique values and have IP from each unique Avalability Zone. For instance I want the output in form of

```
"10.18.13.12, 10.18.37.93"
```

or

```
"10.18.68.147, 10.18.21.55"
```

Is this possible to perform such operations of comparing strings and get its respective value in Jinja template? Anything would help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. The following should do the trick:

```
"{%- for ip, az in seed.iteritems() %} 
  {%- if 'us-east-1a' in az %}
    {%- if firstloop is not defined %}
    {%- set firstloop = 1 %}
{{- ip }}
    {%- else %}
{{- " " + ip}}
    {%- endif %}    
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor%}"
```

To test it with https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/, you can use the following JSON:

```
{
    "seed": {
      "10.18.13.12": "us-east-1a",
      "10.18.37.93": "us-east-1b", 
      "10.18.68.147": "us-east-1a",
      "10.18.21.55": "us-east-1b"
    }
}
```

You might give the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) a read if you are going to be doing much jinja templating. I have found it indispensible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to Jinja and not able to progress on this challenging task. I tested it out on https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/ and getting few errors. It would be great if you can help me solve it

Comment: @Nahush - Nice tool! I've definitely done things like this before. I'll update my answer in a few min with a working example.

Comment: @Nahush - That should do it. Aside from the typos, I had to account for the fact that variables set in a loop are scoped for the life of the loop, and are thus vars set/modified in the loop are unavailable outside the loop. There is a workaround for this using .append() but it is not available on the Jinja version used in your tool, but the above works.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you needed all IPs for us-east, you would change `{%- if 'us-east-1a' in az %}` to `{%- if 'us-east' in az %}`

Comment: that is really great work. I think I am getting IP's from same AZ rather than IP's from unique AZ. I wanted IP's to be one from us-east-1a and one from us-east-1b.